# Using a variable that has yet to be declared

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I have a problem understanding Javascript's engine technique called hoisting.

I've tried to create a `var` in the top of my file to quickly access and edit, but i want to use a variable that has yet to be declared.

First attempt:

```js
var easy_to_edit_value = "some text " + a_yet_to_be_defined_var;

//imagine loads of code so its hard to find the correct funtion to edit the log

function my_function (a_yet_to_be_defined_var){
    console.log(easy_to_edit_value);
}
my_function("more text");
```

This generates an error at line 1 since `a_yet_to_be_defined_var` is not defined.

After looking at this post: [post-by-apsillers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20220928/9496199) i tried again but this time declaring the var without value (so its known but undefined untill declared somewhere futheron)

```js
var a_yet_to_be_defined_var; // now its known so this error is gone
var easy_to_edit_value = "some text " + a_yet_to_be_defined_var;

function my_function (a_yet_to_be_defined_var){
    console.log(easy_to_edit_value);
}
my_function("more text");
//still undefined


//new attempt with a fresh var being set in the function before being called
var new_var;
var easy_to_edit_value = "some text " + new_var;

function my_function2 (a_yet_to_be_defined_var2){
  new_var = a_yet_to_be_defined_var2;
    console.log(easy_to_edit_value);
}
my_function2("more text");
//still undefined
```

But this outputs: `some text undefined` where i was expecting the `some text more text` since i filled the var before asking for it.

Please note these functions aren't ran using `my_function("something")` but are triggered by this: `client.on('message', my_function);`, i've seen arrow function solutions for related questions but i'm not sure how i would get that to work here.

Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: although `a_yet_to_be_defined_var` is declared later on it's not in the same scope as the attempted use and is only available within the scope of `my_function`. Variable hoisting does not work in this situation.

Comment: `new_var` is declared and used before it is given a value - this is a completely different reason for the apparent same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining a value called `easy_to_edit_value`, change it to a function called `easy_to_call_function` that will return `"some text "` concatenated with the current value of `new_var`.

Once a (`var` or `let`) variable is assigned, it must be reassigned or reevaluated each time.

```js
let new_var;
const easy_to_call_function = () => "some text " + new_var;

function my_function2(a_yet_to_be_defined_var2) {
  new_var = a_yet_to_be_defined_var2;
  console.log(easy_to_call_function()); // Call the function
}

my_function2("more text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-declare the variable inside of the function:

```js
var new_var;
var easy_to_edit_value = "some text " + new_var;

function my_function2(a_yet_to_be_defined_var2) {
  new_var = a_yet_to_be_defined_var2;
  easy_to_edit_value = "some text " + new_var;
  console.log(easy_to_edit_value);
}
my_function2("more text");
```

If one variable is changed, other variable ***will not*** update according to the new value. That kind of programming requires a really high level compiler, which not many people are willing to make. The programmer must update variables on their own.

Comment: So this would take editing the `easy_to_edit_value` inside the function to get any effect right? so basicly what i'm trying to achieve is impossible.

Comment: @RamondeVries Yes. I *think* ReactJS has something like that, but I'm not entirely sure.